# How do I create a simple syntax table for a major mode?

Tags: elisp, major-mode, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to understand how syntax tables work, but my minimal major mode doesn't highlight anything.

I've written the following elisp, which is just supposed to highlight comments:

```el
(defconst my-yaml-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((table (make-syntax-table)))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?# "<" table)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">" table)
    table)
  "Syntax table for `my-yaml-mode'.")

(define-derived-mode my-yaml-mode fundamental-mode "My YAML"
  "testing"
  :syntax-table my-yaml-mode-syntax-table)
```

However, given a file:

```
# foo
# bar
baz
```

If I activate my major-mode with `M-x my-yaml-mode`, I don't get any highlighting. `C-u C-x =` shows that no faces have been applied.

Comment: Does `M-;` correctly insert a `#`? If yes, the syntax table is applied. You should look into font-lock specifications to get syntax highlighting.

Comment: `M-;` is bound to `comment-dwim` from newcomment.el, which uses `comment-start` rather than the syntax table. AIUI.

Comment: Hm, indeed, sorry. Instead, you can place the point on a `#` and press `C-u C-x =`, the output should contain the line `syntax: <  which means: comment`.

Comment: Indeed it does! So if my syntax table is correct and is being applied, why isn't there any highlighting?

Comment: After testing with your code, it is simply a matter of turning `font-lock-mode` on in your `my-yaml-mode` buffer. `:)`

Comment: Aha! Would you like to submit an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is correct, but it is not being refontified just because you change major modes.

Enable your major mode and put your cursor in the comment then run  <kbd>M-x</kbd>  `eval-expression` `(syntax-ppss-context (syntax-ppss (point)))`, it should yield 'comment and you'll see that the syntax table is setup correctly.

A simple fix would be to call `(font-lock-fontify-buffer)` when enabling your mode.